# Oracle Appex - database parametrized substitution Strings

Tags: ldap, oracle-apex

I'm trying to enable LDAP authentication and authorization in Oracle APEX. When I go into `Authentication schemes -> Create -> LDAP -> Host` I would like to have that host in some table in my database, is that possible? The host is gonna change with every environment and I would like to avoid manual steps of editing it.

Similar problem with authorization: I have PL/SQL procedure to call LDAP and check if user is in group, for that I need `service_account`, `service_password`, `LDAP host`, `group_name` and I would like them all to be parametrized from some database table.

I know there are substitution Strings that you can embed in PL/SQL procedures etc. (like `V('APP_USER')`), but I don't know how to resolve them from database and if it's even possible.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can use substitution strings, especially if you're referring to the INTERNAL workspace, not just a particular app. At least with an app you could do the LDAP authentication as a custom scheme.

Comment: It's in my app only and it's possible to use substitution Strings, I hardcoded them and it works. The problem is that I need to get them from database, not hardcode them. They are not coming from the client, it's only for automation purposes, no worries about something like malicious injection.

Comment: So at best, you'll need to define application item that calculates on new instance. *Maybe* that will be early enough. *Maybe* the builder will perform the substitution. If not, you'd need to persue custom authentication to do the LDAP authentication, driven by your data.